# Use template-variable as img alt but this is not picked up by search engines

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I use a template variable for my image alt in code such as following:

`<img src="smiley.gif" alt="[*pagetitle*]" height="42" width="42">`

My home-page is heavily loaded with images and somehow around 50% of my images do NOT have alt img text, but the others do. Different SEO tools tell me that. 
I wonder why? And perhaps there is a better way to generate img alt text? Whats an optimal solution?

Now I use a TV as in above example and the input-type is just "text". Nothing fancy.

Comment: Just switch to modx revo - less magic, less problems.

Comment: @Vasis - thanks, but unfortunately too late for that.

Comment: Did you try updating the cache and checking the source code again?